# Create shortcut from vb.net on Windows 7 box (64 bit)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-7, shortcut

I am trying to create a desktop shortcut from vb.net code on a Windows 7 box (64 bit).  The following code works on XP, but when run on Win7 I just get a message stating the App has stopped working:

```
Imports IWshRuntimeLibrary

Dim WshShell As WshShellClass = New WshShellClass

            Dim MyShortcut As IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut

            ' The shortcut will be created on the desktop
            'Win 7 
            MyShortcut = CType(WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\iexplore.lnk"), IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)

            'MyShortcut = CType(WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\iexplore.lnk"), IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)

            MyShortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" 'Specify target app full path
            MyShortcut.Description = "IE"

            MyShortcut.Save()
```

Any thoughts or better ways to create a shorcut from code on a Win7 box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 64-bit here.  Compiled this as 32-bit and it worked:

```
Imports IWshRuntimeLibrary

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim WshShell As WshShell = New WshShell

        Dim MyShortcut As IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut

        MyShortcut = CType(WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Dah Browser.lnk"), IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)
        MyShortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" 'Specify target app full path
        MyShortcut.Description = "IE"

        MyShortcut.Save()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Note: I am  running as admin with UAC turned off.

Also notice I changed WshShellClass to WshShell

Comment: Oh, and I haven't done VB in years.  Thanks for the mental exercise.  :)

Comment: The question is asking how to do this on 64 bit Windows. That is not a 64 bit solution. It is a 32 bit solution. The code shown will not compile in a 64 bit application.

Answer (score 0):

What privileges is your app running under?  I believe it will need admin credentials to do what you are looking for.

Comment: The account is an Administrator

Comment: that is not the same as running elevated. Unless it's a service, it's subject to UAC. If it's an installer, it's probably elevated, and if it's an ordinary app, it probably isn't.

Comment: UAC is off so that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: So you see the same behaviour when you run as administrator?

Comment: Yes Administrator account, UAC off, even right click app and Run As Administrator.

Comment: This is something that should generally be run via an elevated installer anyway.